# Tree View for Document Library doesn't work

Tags: document-library, 2013

I have two column. First column is the nav part but it's empty. My doc library is in the second part. What's wrong with my code? The Id's are true.

My tree view code:

```
        <table style="width: 100%">
           <tr valign="top">
            <td style="width: 20%">

            <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl id="doclibDataSource" runat="server" RootListId="ListId"
        RootWebId="WebId" ShowFolderChildren="true" EnableViewState="false">
        </SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl>
        <SharePoint:SPTreeView ID="doclibtreeview" runat="server" DataSourceID="doclibDataSource" EnableViewState="false" ExpandDepth="2"
        SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected">
        </SharePoint:SPTreeView>
            </td>
            <td>

                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
                    LISTWEBPART
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the values of RootListId and RootWebId ​​in GUID format

```
<table style="width: 100%"> <tr valign="top"> <td width="20%">

<SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl id="doclibDataSource" runat="server" RootListId="b15e1faa-a4dc-4f5f-bcaf-ec16009118ac" RootWebId="fb9ceab3-8128-401e-96d6-ea72f3a0f03a" ShowFolderChildren="true" EnableViewState="false"  > </SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl> <SharePoint:SPTreeView ID="doclibtreeview" runat="server"  DataSourceID="doclibDataSource" EnableViewState="false" ExpandDepth="1"  SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected"> </SharePoint:SPTreeView>

</td> <td>
```